# How to avoid repeated const and non-const virtual functions ? is it possible?

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, virtual-functions

Suppose I have a base class with the following [virtual](/questions/tagged/virtual) function:

```
virtual int* get(){ return nullptr; }
```

*and*

I would like to supply a `const` version (bear in mind I have in ballpark of 50 different implementations in legacy code)

```
const int* get() const { return const_cast<decltype(this)>(this)->GetReturn(); };//NEED CODE BADLY: const_cast :/
```

But this idea needs to use a `const_cast` - scott meyer's suggest this approach in his book (albeit the situation is reversed) - but is it really safe (if yes, is it 'future-proof' as well?) from for example members being const ?

I can reverse the situation with some search/replace but having both implementations on all classes seems to be too much 'copy-paste' antipattern.

Comment: The reverse is more safe, your version relies on the fact that non-const method doesn't modify internal. No guaranties (even more with polymorphism as you got less control on implementation).

Comment: This is not safe in general. Calling a nonconst function through a const reference is UB unless it's referring to an object that was declared nonconst. UB or not you can also break const semantics this way.

Comment: @Cubic - No, attempting to modify an object declared const is UB. If the member function doesn't do that, there is no UB. Even though it's not const-correct.

Comment: Classic [XY problerm](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @MarekR Disagree. This is such a common thing that like... Scott Meyers has a whole item in a book about it (Item 3 in Effective C++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but is it really safe

Unfortunately not:

Variant 1:

```
class C
{
    int n;
public:
    int* get() { ++n; return &n; }
    int const* get() const { return const_cast<decltype(this)>(this)->get(); }
};
```

Variant 2:

```
class C
{
    int const n;
public:
    int const* get() const { return &n; }
    int* get() { return const_cast<int*>(const_cast<decltype(this) const*>(this)->get()); }
    void demo() // non-const!
    {
        ++*get();
    }
};
```

Admitted, the second case might not be too probable – but not impossible either. So in any of the two variants, there's an opportunity hidden to raise undefined behaviour...